# Laravel repository best practice

Tags: php, laravel

Is it bad practice to call `auth()->user()` to get the authenticated user in a Laravel repository method?

The alternative would be to pass the user object into the method, but it seems strange to pass in a variable when it's globally available.

Comment: Could you elaborate why doing so is a bad practice? I can't figure out. In small sized projects, it's really common for me to write it direclly on model class

Comment: It seems strange to have to 'log in' in order to test a repository method. I don't know what the best practice is though.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have enough reputation to comment the post so i ll just add an answer..
I think passing the user object to the method is usually better because it makes the method more versatile. Because you can create a new user and pass it to the method without the need of having a logged user (could be useful for quickly testing the method for example). The controller should handle the logic of passing the correct user to the method imo